# Image is not fitted when used in leading of ListTile

Tags: flutter

The asset image is 200x200px, but when it used in leading of ListTile it's not fitted as axpected.
The rendered image looks this way. How to display it proportioanlly 90x90 as it's defined in Image height and width properties?

[image]

```
Card(
  key: ValueKey(favorites[index]),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
  child: ListTile(
    leading: kNoImage,
    title: Text(favorites[index]),
    subtitle: Text(favorites[index]),
    trailing: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
      onPressed: () {
        debugPrint('entry deleted');
      },
    ),
  ),
);

const kNoImage = Image(
  image: AssetImage('assets/no-user-image.png'),
  height: 90,
  width: 90,
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
);
```

Comment: I prefer not to use `ListTile` because of it default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the value of `fit` to something like `BoxFit.scaleDown` or `BoxFit.contain` to get the desired result. See the [BoxFit docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html) to see what these values mean.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html is the docs for if it helps

Answer (score 0):

The max height for leading widget for your case is ≈56px.

So, if you want to explicitly want to keep it 90, I'd suggest you to make your own ListTile with `Row()` and `Column()` which is pretty easy.

This is what I found in ListTile(),

```dart
final Offset baseDensity = visualDensity.baseSizeAdjustment;
if (isOneLine)
  return (isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0) + baseDensity.dy;
if (isTwoLine)
  return (isDense ? 64.0 : 72.0) + baseDensity.dy;
return (isDense ? 76.0 : 88.0) + baseDensity.dy;
```

Answer (score -1):

I prefer not to use ListTile because of it default behavior. Therefor, I prefer

[on dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e079c0e90179393ad27de7c0be132489&null_safety=true) or on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/yeasin50/e079c0e90179393ad27de7c0be132489)

**Custom ListTile**

```dart
 Card(
          elevation: 8,
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(defaultBorderRadiusCircular),
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 6),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 90.0,
                      height: 90.0,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.circular(defaultBorderRadiusCircular),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'imagePath',
                          width: 90,
                          height: 90,
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 24,
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'Danau Beretan',
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          'Indonesia',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.star_half_outlined),
                    Text("4.5"),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]